# Creating multiple jars using maven without using profiles configuration

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-plugin

I have a maven project created with standard structure and one addtional source folder. The project structure is as below.

```
- my_project
    - src/main/java
    - src/main/resources/
    - src/test/java
    - src/test/resources
    - <my_source_folder>
```

Now I want to create two jars from my project using single maven goal-

1. main.jar (which excludes my_source_folder).
2. my.jar (which includes my_source_folder and excludes src/main/java)

**Update:**

The use case for which I want to do this is as below :

I want to create two jars - a slim jar and an implementation jar from a project.

1. The **slim jar** which contains apis/interfaces and some lightweight slim classes
2. The **impl jar** which contains actual implementations of apis/interfaces.

Can anyone please suggest what approach could be better to address this?

Comment: Please don't do this. This is against Maven philosophy. I guess there are way better approaches to achieve what you really want.

Comment: @JFMeier Can you please suggest the approach I can take?

Comment: This is what Maven _modules_ are for.

Answer (score 1):

Create two separate modules in a multi-module project.

Alternatively, create two separate projects.